# Silverstripe prompts for authentication

Tags: apache, authentication, wamp, wampserver, silverstripe

we recently moved a website to another server and updated SilverStripe to the latest version.

**Now(!), when trying to access the site, there is a username/password prompt:**

[image]

I searched around a little and tried a few things. I don't know much about Apache/SilverStripe authentication. This is all the information I can give:

- We are using the latest WampServer
- The site's directory is `...\wamp\www\sitename` and (for now) accessed like `http:\\localhost\sitename\`
- We have a bunch of other sites on the same web server (WordPress blogs), but the authentication issue occurs only on the SilverStripe site
- There are no authentication settings in the `httpd.conf` file or any of the `.htaccess` files in the site's directory
- It is possible to change the username/password required for the authentication with `Security::setDefaultAdmin("username", "password")`
- After authenticating, one's redirected to the start page (`.../sitename/container/home/`, I guess this is correct)
- The issue occurs only once on each client machine, when accessing the site for the first time. After that, one's redirected immediately every time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds as though you have basic authentication turned on, probably triggered by your change in environment.

This will be set in your application somewhere - probably in _ss_environment.php or _config.php of your project.

API Docs for BasicAuth are here: http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-BasicAuth.html

Comment: After reading your answer it took me exactly 10 seconds to locate the cause: `BasicAuth::protect_entire_site();` in `mysite\_config.php`. Thanks!